# webScraping ¿ Como obtengo el href y el src de esta pagina dinámica? Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, href

Buen día amigos, Estoy haciendo web scraping a  una pagina para  mi proyecto, pero no logro sacar los href y el src de la pagina :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacer:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
for elem in elems:
print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Pero nada

al igual que usar selectores

Comment: Estas utilizando BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con la librería BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ algo como:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
phtml = 'tupagina.com'

page = requests.get(phtml)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing__link'})
imgs = soup.findAll('img', {'class':'listing-img__img'})

for l in links:
    try:
        print(l['href'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

for i in imgs:
    try:
        print(i['src'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```